# Why does my C code not work everytime?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, gcc, merge

I wrote this code to merge two sorted arrays. The desired output is:

```
Merged array:0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

I am using gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609 to compile my code.

The problem is that sometimes I get the desired output when I execute the a.out file but on other occasions, the cursor keeps blinking and no result is shown. Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){

//change arrays as per your need but it should be sorted
int a[] = {1,2,3,7,8};
int b[] = {0,3,5,6,9,10,11,12};

int m =sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
int n =sizeof(b) / sizeof(int);

int index=0, j=0, k=0;
int size = m + n;
int array[size];


while(index < size) {

    while(a[j] < b[k] && j<m ){
        array[index] = a[j];
        ++index;
        ++j;
    }
    while(a[j] > b[k] && k<n){
        array[index] = b[k];
        ++index;
        ++k;            
    }
    while(a[j] == b[k]){
        array[index] = a[j];
        j++; index++;            
    }        
}

printf("Merged array: ");
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    printf("%d ", array[i]);

printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: haaave you tried debugging it? ....

Comment: I don't know how to debug yet. I was not familiar with it. This for pointing it out, I'll learn it soon.

Comment: The most important tool for a developer is the debugger, especially if you are a beginner. I know that they don't teach debugging, mostly they don't even mention it. But you need to invest a few hours to learn how to debug your programs. **It will save you countless hours** of staring at your code asking yourself why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much bolov, you are right it was not mentioned anywhere. I will surely learn to debug as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with my code?

Yes!

It gets out of bounds when accessing `a`, here for example:

```
while(a[j] < b[k] && j<m ){
    array[index] = a[j];
    ++index;
    ++j;
}
```

`j` will eventually get the value 4, enter the body of the if statement, and when it tries to resolve the condition of the while loop, it will access `a[5]`, which is out of bounds, thus causing *Undefined Behavior* (which explains why your code runs sometimes, and others hang).

You could let short circuiting help you by changing your while loop's condition to this:

```
while(j < m && a[j] < b[k]) {
```

which when `j` reaches `m`m, resulting in `j<m` evaluated to false, will not go through `a[j] < b[k]`, because a logical and operation will be false, if at least one of its operands are false.

Same happens in your next while loop. So change it to this:

```
while(k < n && a[j] > b[k]) {
```

Last, but not least, the condition of the last while loop:

```
while(a[j] == b[k]){
```

will also invoke Undefined Behavior, since `j` will be equal to 5, and `k` equal to 8.

Changing it to:

```
while(j < m && k < n && a[j] == b[k]) {
```

will prevent Undefined Behavior from being invoked.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome find. Is there any way to deal with this problem in while(a[j] == b[k]) ?

Comment: `while(k<n a[j] > b[k]) {` Should this be `while(k<n && a[j] > b[k]) {`

Comment: gsamarsa I made the changes you pointed out but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

You have undefined behaviour (accessing the array out of bounds). Use `gcc -fsanitize=undefined` to create an executable that can detect all sorts of bad behaviour.

```
% gcc -g fffff.c -Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=undefined
% ./a.out
fffff.c:20:12: runtime error: index 5 out of bounds for type 'int [5]'
fffff.c:20:12: runtime error: load of address 0x7ffd0c0c9804 with insufficient space for an object of type 'int'
0x7ffd0c0c9804: note: pointer points here
  08 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  05 00 00 00 06 00 00 00
              ^ 
fffff.c:25:12: runtime error: index 5 out of bounds for type 'int [5]'
fffff.c:25:12: runtime error: load of address 0x7ffd0c0c9804 with insufficient space for an object of type 'int'
0x7ffd0c0c9804: note: pointer points here
  08 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  05 00 00 00 06 00 00 00
              ^ 
fffff.c:30:12: runtime T: index 5 out of bounds for type 'int [5]'
fffff.c:30:12: runtime error: load of address 0x7ffd0c0c9804 with insufficient space for an object of type 'int'
0x7ffd0c0c9804: note: pointer points here
  08 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
```

The lines 20, 25 and 30 are

```
20      while(a[j] < b[k] && j<m ){

25      while(a[j] > b[k] && k<n){

30      while(a[j] == b[k]){
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am not familiar with debugging. Will learn it asap.

Comment: @V-ZarD one thing to note is that you'd use this to quickly find problem spots, then you can use the debugger to step through the code and inspect values